# How to create multiple objects along with a foreignkey whose foreignkey field is provided?

Tags: python, django

```
class User(models.Model):
   email = models.EmailField()


class Lawyer(models.Model):

   user = models.OnetoOneField(User)

class Session(models.Model):

  lawyer = models.ForeignKey(Lawyer)

  name = models.TextField()


class SessionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  email = serializers.EmailField()
  class Meta:
      model = Session
      fields=['name', 'lawyer','email']
```

I do not have the lawyer id in the request , my request contains only email  and name of the session.

I need to create multiple objects with session serializer but how to save the lawyer by using the email that is passed?

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. If you don't have the lawyer, where is it supposed to be coming from?

Comment: @Ananthakrishnan M A  Do you only have the email of lawyer in the client side which is in the user table?

Comment: @Ananthakrishnan M A Are you trying to get the lawyer by the email field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all you need is to create the `Lawyer`, also you should set allow null to true for the `laweyer` field.

```
class SessionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  email = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
  lawyer = serializers.IntegerField(allow_null=True, required=False)

  fields=['name', 'lawyer','email']

  def create(self, validated_data):
     user = User.objects.create(email=validated_data.get('email'))
     lawyer = Lawyer.objects.create(user=user)
     name = validated_data.get('name')
     instance = Session.objects.create(lawyer=lawyer, name=name)
     return instance
```

Comment: Can a SerializerMethodField() be used to fetch lawyer from the email passed?

Comment: it does not need

Comment: What about multiple objects creation ??

Comment: what about list serializer ??

Comment: i don't understand what do you want for the OP question?

Comment: I am learning something similar to this , I just want to know how to override the create/ bulk create for a list serializer.

Comment: unfortunately i don't clear what you really need, i think it better to find the answer on the SO or create your own question.